# Searching for n-th child in n-th parent

Tags: selenium, xpath, nested, containers

There is a strange behaviour when it comes to finding elements by xpath. The situation:

```
<body>
...
  <div class="ingredients-group">
    <div class="group-header">
      <h3>Title 1</h3>
      ... other stuff
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="ingredients-group">
    <div class="group-header">
      <h3>Title 2</h3>
      ... other stuff
    </div>
  </div>
...
```

I want to check the text of the H3 tag on the second ingredient-group. So I did the following in Selenium:

```
WebElement group2 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='ingredients-group'][2]"));
WebElement title2 = group2.findElement(By.xpath("//h3"));
String titleText = title2.GetText();
```

The last statement returns "Title 1". I would expect it to return "Title 2".

Strangely, this statement returns "Title 2":

```
String titleText = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='ingredients-group'][2]//h3")).getText();
```

I would like to use the first option (group2.findElement), because there are several other elements in the containers I would like to refer to without having to write the full xpath.

Any ideas on this?
Thanks

Comment: The one you think is "strange" is returning exactly what it should.  You are going to the 2nd instance of @class='ingredients-group' and returning the title of the h3 tag associated with it, 'Title 2'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use findElements to return a list of webelements (h3 tags) and then access them as you would any other list:

```
WebElement groups = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='ingredients-group'][2]"));
WebElement theH3Tag = groups[0].findElement(By.xpath(".//h3")); //make this a relative xpath
String titleText = theH3Tag.GetText();  

WebElement the2ndH3Tag = groups[1].findElement(By.xpath(".//h3")); //make this a relative xpath
String titleText = the2ndH3Tag.GetText();
```

Or loop through the list:

```
    WebElement[] groups = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='ingredients-group'][2]"));
    for (WebElement group : groups) {
        WebElement h3Tag = group.findElement(By.xpath(".//h3")); //make this a relative xpath
        String titleText = h3Tag.GetText();
    }
```

Comment: Switching to driver.findElements dod not help. But meanwhile I figured out the problem. The H3 tags are dynamic. They are not displayed at the time when Selenium is executing findElement or findElements using xpath. But when I try to find elements using By.id, it works properly. Selenium somehow doesn´t recognize hidden elements using xpath.

Comment: So you just need to add waitFor?

Comment: A tiny dot solves it all. I in findElement by XPath I was using "//h3" instead of ".//h3". In my case Selenium was searching for h3 in the whole DOM and found the first one instead of seraching inside the desired group element. Thank you all for your comments. The case is closed.